# Download Custom Table HTML to Excel Using Table2excel Plugin

Tags: excel, download

I am trying to download table HTML using table2excel plugin.

I can download all column in table with this code:

```
<table id="empTable">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>Alpha</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>Bandung</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>Bravo</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>Bali</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#empTable").table2excel({
        filename: "Employees.xls"
    });
 });
</script>
```

I am success to download table with all column (ID, Name, Age, Address). How to download as excel partial of column table? I only want to download column ID, Name, and Age without column Address. How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table2excel` has an option to exclude cells that contain a specified class. In the example below, I add the `noExport` class to the cells I don't want to export. They are ignored when the file is created.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#export').on('click', function(e){
        $("#table").table2excel({
            exclude: ".noExport",
            name: "Data",
            filename: "Workbook",
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
<button id="export">Export</button>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="noExport">This cell won't be exported.</td>
      <td>This cell will get exported.</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td class="noExport">Ipsum</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Admittedly, this could get tedious to do for an entire column. Fortunately, a GitHub user forked table2excel and made a modification that allows you to specify which columns you want to export.

See: https://github.com/davidkonrad/table2excel

Using his version of table2excel, it'd look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#export').on('click', function(e){
        $("#table").table2excel({
            exclude: ".noExport",
            name: "Data",
            filename: "Workbook",
            columns: [0, 1, 2] // export first three columns
        });
    });
});
```

Note that there does appear to be a bug with opening table2excel workbooks in some versions of Excel. You might get a warning saying the file extension doesn't match. But if you ignore this warning, it should load in Excel without further issue.

Comment: thank you @AndroidNoobie, this work correctly. I also want to download html custom table to PDF like that, have you good recomendation plugin to do that?